# Error: tinyformat: Not enough conversion specifiers in format string R FlexScan

Tags: r, statistics

I am using the rflexscan package to run a spatial scan statistics on some point data. When I have run the code in the past, it has worked perfectly; however, I'm using it on a new dataset and getting this error:

```
`Error: tinyformat: Not enough conversion specifiers in format string`
```

this is the code that I am using:

```
# run FleXScan
    expected <- data$population*(sum(data$cases)/sum(data$population))

    fls <- rflexscan(x = data$long, y = data$lat,
             observed = data$cases,
             expected = expected,
             name = rownames(data),
             clustersize = 5, #limits the number of facilities that can be in a cluster
             nb = col005.w.mat, #this is the network object that we created on lines 33-35
             scanmethod="CIRCULAR",
             rantype="POISSON",
             simcount = 999,
             stattype="ORIGINAL",
             secondary=NULL,
             clustertype="HOT")
```

My dataset has 225 observations in the following format:

- facility [character]
- population [integer]
- lat [numeric]
- long [numeric]
- cases [integer]